# invalid URL escape "%+o"

Tags: go, url

I need to parse urls (coming from various sources) and get from them the usual suspects: host, query, ...

I wrote the following code (runnable [here](http://%20https://play.golang.org/p/nL3SEvjZ8pu)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func gethost(line string) string {
    u, err := url.Parse(line)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return string(u.Host)
}

func main() {
    host := gethost("https://www.percent-off.com/_20_%+off_60000_")
    fmt.Println(host)
}
```

which fails with the error :

> parse "https://www.percent-off.com/*20*%+off_60000_": invalid URL escape "%+o"

I noticed many similar questions about the module net/url which involve invalid url escape.
In [DotNet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QhE88D), the equivalent code works well and properly returns.

```
using System;

Console.WriteLine(new Uri("https://www.percent-off.com/_20_%+off_60000_").Host);
```

Is there a more reliable way to parse urls in Go?

Comment: You have an invalid URL. The most reliable way to parse an invalid URL is to return an error.

Comment: In that case, .Net and browsers are objectively wrong. This isn't a matter of opinion. It's a matter of [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1). And nobody ever said any "framework" was better than another, for any reason, least of all "just because". I really have no idea what you're referring to with that retort.

Comment: The `%` character is used in URL encoding to indicate the start of an escaped character, eg `%0f` is a space. `%+o` isn't anything, so it is invalid according to the URL spec. Other clients may attempt to treat this as a valid URL by making certain assumptions about it, and sometimes their assumptions may be correct, and other times their assumptions may lead to unexpected behavior. Go's client is strict - when it gets an invalid URL, it returns an error rather than making a guess. Neither is better or worse, simply different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same basic issue has been brought up on the [Go issue tracker](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29808).

TL;DR; The URL in question (both yours, and the one in the linked issue) are obviously invalid, so the error is *correct*.

That said, there has been discussion about making the parser more forgiving of such errors, but apparently no conclusion or action plan has been formulated.

If you truly need this support, you'll probably have to write your own URL parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    s := "https://www.percent-off.com/_20_%+off_60000_"

    // url parse: fix invalid URL escape
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`%(25)?`)
    s = re.ReplaceAllLiteralString(s, "%25")

    // parse url
    parse, err := url.Parse(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("parsed:", parse)

    return
}
```

[source](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/pull/319)